# New PC build with one long and two short beeps

Tags: bios, computer-building

I built my first PC, and I get a 1 long and 2 short beeps which I believe is RAM.

- MB: ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0 AMD3+ R
- CPU: AMD 6 CORE FX 6300 3.5G 8m R
- PSU: EVGA 100-B1-0500-KR R 500B 500W Bronze
- HDD: 1T WD WD10EZEX SATA6G %
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance LP 8 GB CML8GX3M1A1600C10 One Stick Black Version
- GPU: ASUS Radeon HD 7870 DirectCU II

The RAM fits, but I don't hear a click.

Comment: 1 Long, 2 Short beeps is no RAM detected. Do you have one or two sticks of RAM?

Comment: one stick of ram

Comment: check your mobo manual, they'll say what RAM is supported. that mobo support DDR1600? Is that DDR2 or DDR3?

Comment: Wrong ram type shouldn't fit. Have you tried one of the other ram slots (if any)?

Comment: The RAM should run, if meets the spec for this motherboard: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_LE_R20/#specifications Although, it's not listed on the Qualified Vendor List: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_LE_R20/#support

Comment: I'd also check if the ram is seated properly. Just to rule out the most obvious possibility. Remove it, make sure it all lines up, make sure its pushed all the way in and *clipped* in place.

Comment: You hear a distinctive click sound when RAM is seated and the locks on either side will fit perfectly in notches on the stick i.e. they are not inclined but exactly perpendicular to MoBo in correct position.

Comment: Its not on vendors list and it goes into slot but i dont hear click. tried all the slots, says to put in a2.

Comment: supports ddr3 1600

Answer (score 0):

I would check the seating forst as well but looking at your MB it doesn’t seem your Corsair is  supported (that doesn’t mean that it *won’t* work) - look [here for specs on the M5A97 R2.0](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/#support_QVL)
.

The only Corsair listed is CMZ16GX3M2A2400C10 and you have to have **2 of them for 16GB total**

Answer (score 0):

One long two short beeps is often a [video error on most motherboard/bioses](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm). I would suggest removing your GPU and seeing if it POSTs then.